# Como ordenar uma diretiva ngFor em Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Tenho um array de produto, no html eu faço um for e consigo normalmente receber os dados certinho, mas não estou sabendo ordenar esse array através do atributo faltaDePecas. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Obrigado!

'''

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
  
  <ion-label>
    <h2>({{ produto.cod }}) {{ produto.descricao }} {{ produto.qtdDisponivel }}/{{ produto.capMaxima }} (min: {{ produto.qtdMinima }}) teste:{{ produto.faltaDePecas }}
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

'''

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Proponho 3 soluções:

1 - Ordenar o array de objetos no seu controller.

```
produtos.sort((a, b) => (a.faltaDePecas< b.faltaDePecas? -1 : 1));
```

2- Criar um pipe com a mesma lógica acima.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let produto of produtos|pipe-customizado">
```

3- Importar um pipe já pronto ex: ngx-order-pipe https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-order-pipe

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let produto of produtos| orderBy: 'faltaDePecas'">
```

Comment: Consegui com a primeira solução, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: se puder sinaliza a resposta como certa depois. abraço